# Athena Query permissions from lambda, store results in s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, amazon-athena

I have a lambda function running a query on athena and is putting the output location to an s3 bucket. I get a permissions error and can't figure out why.

error:

```
AthenaErrorCode: "INSUFFICIENT_PERMISSIONS",
Message_: "Unable to verify/create output bucket my-s3-bucket"
```

lambda policy:

```yaml
Policies:
        - Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Action:
                - athena:GetWorkGroup
                - s3:PutObject
                - s3:GetObject
                - athena:StartQueryExecution
                - s3:AbortMultipartUpload
                - lambda:InvokeFunction
                - athena:CancelQueryExecution
                - athena:StopQueryExecution
                - athena:GetQueryExecution
                - athena:GetQueryResults
                - s3:ListMultipartUploadParts
              Resource:
                - !Sub "arn:aws:athena:*:${AWS::AccountId}:workgroup/primary"
                - !Sub "arn:aws:s3:::${my-s3-bucket}/*"
            - Effect: Allow
              Action:
                - athena:ListWorkGroups
              Resource: "*"
            - Effect: Allow
              Action:
                - s3:ListBucket
                - s3:GetBucketLocation
              Resource:
                - !Sub "arn:aws:s3:::${my-s3-bucket}/*"
```

my bucket exists already and is created in the cf template; here is the policy

```yaml
DevQueryResultsPolicy:
    Type: 'AWS::S3::BucketPolicy'
    Properties:
      Bucket: !Ref DevQueryResultsBucket
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Sid: AllowSSLRequestsOnly # AWS Foundational Security Best Practices v1.0.0 S3.5
            Effect: Deny
            Principal: '*'
            Action: 's3:*'
            Resource:
              - !GetAtt 'DevQueryResultsBucket.Arn'
              - !Sub '${DevQueryResultsBucket.Arn}/*'
            Condition:
              Bool:
                'aws:SecureTransport': false
```

finally, the code in the lambda:

```golang
// athena service
    svc := athena.New(sess, aws.NewConfig().WithRegion("us-east-1"))

    // create query
    var s athena.StartQueryExecutionInput
    fmt.Println(tables[0])
    s.SetQueryString(fmt.Sprintf("select * from %s limit 10", tables[0]))

    // set db for query
    var q athena.QueryExecutionContext
    q.SetDatabase("MYDB")
    s.SetQueryExecutionContext(&q)

    // setup output location to s3
    var r athena.ResultConfiguration
    r.SetOutputLocation("s3://my-s3-bucket")
    s.SetResultConfiguration(&r)

    // execute query
    result, err := svc.StartQueryExecution(&s)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("execution error ----", err)
        return serverError(ctx, errors.New("query failed to execute"))
    }
```

Comment: Looks like you are missing s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads. Can you verify if you have all actions from here https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/athena-output-bucket-error/ ?

Comment: @PrabhakarReddy trying this out now

Comment: @PrabhakarReddy it still doesn't seem to work. same error.  I will check back tomorrow

Comment: @PrabhakarReddy this seemed to work, i will accept as answer

Answer (score 0):

The Lambda's IAM Policy that you are using in your template is missing`s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads`. Please refer to [this](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/athena-output-bucket-error/) document for all required IAM permissions required for Athena to write to output bucket.